# Trying to Paint GUI using Timer and Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

For this small program I am attempting to generate a list of squares to be drawn on a panel. Each thread will generate a list and then set the list in the GUI class. In the GUI class I have a swing timer which repaints the panel every 500 milliseconds. Whenever a thread completes their set of squares I want to display it in the GUI. I also want to be sure to overwrite the variable so that the squares from one set do not overlap with another. My program consists of a custom thread class, a main class, a GUI class, and a custom jpanel class. I understand that currently the threads are quite fast, but if they each took different amounts of time, I still am getting data race errors if 2 threads generate a solution at the same time. Is there some sort of waiting function that can occur where a thread will not be able to overwrite until another thread has finished?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

class Custom extends Thread {
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Point> squarelist = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private static volatile CopyOnWriteArrayList<CopyOnWriteArrayList<Point>> listoflists = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private GUI g;

    Custom(GUI g) {
        this.g = g;

    }

    private void generate() {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * (600 - 20 + 1) + 20);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * (600 - 20 + 1) + 50);
        squarelist.add(new Point(x,y));
    }

    public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                generate();
            }

            CopyOnWriteArrayList<Point> copy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(squarelist);
            System.out.println("SOLUTION = " + copy.toString());
            listoflists.add(copy);

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                g.setSquares(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(copy));

            });

    }


}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GUI g = new GUI();
            g.setVisible(true);
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[32];
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                threads[i] = new Custom(g);
                threads[i].start();
            }



        });
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

    private MyPanel m;

    GUI()  {
        initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, e -> {
            m.setPaint();
            m.repaint();
        });
        int height = 600;
        int width = 600;
        m = new MyPanel(height, width);
        this.setSize(1000,1000);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(m);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    void setSquares(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Point> squarelist) {
        m.setSquares(squarelist);
    }

}

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private boolean paint;
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Point> squarelist;

    MyPanel(int h, int w) {
        squarelist = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        paint = false;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        this.setBackground(Color.pink);
        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        this.setBorder(blackline);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(paint) {
            for(Point p : squarelist) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawRect((int) p.getX(),(int) p.getY(),20,20);
                g.fillRect((int) p.getX(),(int) p.getY(),20,20);
            }
        }
    }

    void setPaint() {
        paint = true;
    }

    void setSquares(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Point> squarelist) {
        this.squarelist = squarelist;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at this and tell me/us if this is answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232795/how-to-paint-in-java-swing-in-every-concurrent-thread/64233022#64233022

Comment: Ok, I have looked at that solution, and am wondering, would I just remove a shape from the list when it gets drawn? If I don't want it to stay in the list. If I have a list of shapes that I want to get drawn at the same time, then I have to modify the collection itself instead of just adding new points to it.

Comment: Also, should I make "squarelist" in the jpanel class final? When I use synchronized on it, it gives me a little warning